# ArrayList and ListView are not being populated

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am completely lost and have no idea why my `ListView` is not being populated. In my method where I am inserting data into my `ArrayList`, it says my `adapter` symbol cannot be resolved, but as far as I know I have properly declared the adapter in my `onCreate`.

Am I correct in assuming that if I have a `ListView` inside of my activity, set up an `ArrayList` that fills my adapter, and then tie that adapter to the `ListView` that my `ListView` will auto-populate in my activity whenever the `array` receives information?

Here are my declarations inside of my `onCreate`.

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dispScores);
    ArrayList<viewScores> savedScores = new ArrayList<viewScores>();
    ScoreAdapter adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, savedScores);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

These are the methods I am using to add data into my `ArrayList`.

```
public View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scorePrompt);
        TextView output1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTotal);
        String blankCheck = input1.getText().toString(); //CHANGE INPUT IN scorePrompt TO STRING
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttTotal:
                    if (blankCheck.equals("")) {
                        Toast blankError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU CANT SKIP HOLES JERK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        blankError.show();
                        break;
                     } else {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString()); //Get input from text box
                        int sum = num1 + score2;
                        score2 = sum;
                        output1.setText("Your score is : " + Integer.toString(sum));

                        //ATTEMPTING TO WRITE TO ARRAYLIST
                        viewScores addScore = new viewScores(input1.getText().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        adapter.add(addScore); //WHY DOESNT THIS WORK?
                        j++;
                        input1.setText(""); //Clear input text box
                        break;
                    }
            case R.id.allScores: //CHANGE THIS TO AN EDIT BUTTON, ADD A HOLE NUMBER COUNTER AT TOP OF SCREEN!!!!!
                output1.setText("you messed up");
                break;
            case R.id.editScore: //Need to set up Save Array before we can edit
                //CURRENTLY ONLY DISPLAYS THE LAST NUNMBER IN THE TEXTEDIT, NEED TO SET UP LISTVIEW!!!!!!
                for (int i=0; i < j; i++){
                //    output1.setText(savedScores.get(i));
                } break;
        }
    }
};

public class viewScores {
    public String hole;
    public viewScores(String holeNum) {
        this.hole = holeNum;
    }
}

public class ScoreAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<viewScores> {
    public ScoreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<viewScores> scores) {
        super(context, 0, scores);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewScores score1 = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        }
        TextView ListView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dispScores);
        ListView1.setText(score1.hole);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The app doesn't crash and I am able to enter values into my `EditText`. Below is the XML for the `ListView`.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/dispScores"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="244dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you update the model observed by your adapter, you need to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

So in your case,

```
viewScores addScore = new viewScores(input1.getText().toString());
savedScores.add(addScore);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding and everything, but by model do you mean the `ArrayList`? I am unsure as to where I should be calling this function.

Comment: Yes, since your adapter's items are based on your ArrayList, everytime you add to this ArrayList, your adapter should be notified that a new item has been added via adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Also, I believe you should be adding to your ArrayList, not the actual adapter. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okay that is really good to know thank you! However, I am still encountering the problem where whenever I call "adapter" in my `onClickListener` method, I am seeing that I get the error "unable to resolve symbol 'adapter'. would you happen to have any idea why this is so (same problem for calling savedScores in this method)?

Comment: Most probably because you're declaring adapter inside your onCreate method, and then trying to use it outside of that method. 

Here's a nice introduction to the concept of variable scopes: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm